# Why don't I get CSS class intellisense from CSS files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

One of the nice features of **VS2012** was that when I'm editing an HTML (or .cshtml) file, it provided great intellisense.

When I start to type:

```
<a href="
```

The editor would open a prompt with "Pick URL..." and a list of possible options based on the current directory of the file.

[image: Pick URL example]

*^ Visual Studio 2012*

Furthermore, in VS2012 the editor would **detect any referenced CSS file(s)**, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
```

And would provide autocompletion of all CSS classes inside that file.

So if I type:

```
<div class="
```

I would be prompted with all Bootstrap3 classes automatically. Like this:

[image: CSS class intellisense]

*^ Visual Studio 2012*

However in **VS2013** both of these features seem to be missing.

Now when I look for CSS classes I only get classes that I've already used inside the file:

[image: VS2013 CSS completion]

*^ Visual Studio 2013*

According to the articles [HTML Editing Features in Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx) and [HTML Editing Features in Visual Studio 2013 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/30/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-rc.aspx) by Microsoft, these issues seem to be touched on but are more aimed at the Release Candidate or beta versions of VS2013. I'm using VS2013 Ultimate 12.0.21005.1 REL with all the latest update that I'm aware of.

Why is VS2013 not detecting CSS files for class autocompletion and not prompting me for URLs when writing `href=`?

Comment: Having the same CSS class name issue with VS2013 Express for Web.

Comment: Just in case this helps someone else, I was having this issue because I forgot to install Web Essentials 2013. As soon as I installed Web Essentials the issue was resolved.

Comment: Even with Visual Studio 2013.1 and Web Essentials 2013 1.8 I still don't get the CSS class autocompletion for linked style sheets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was **a change between Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013**.

Previously, simply opening a file in Visual Studio 2012 (not a solution, just an HTML file) and using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
```

in the HTML file meant that Visual Studio would read inside the CSS file and give CSS class intellisense. Microsoft abandoned this approach, because:

> it failed to work in cases where files were included dynamically, or where ASP.NET Bundling and Minification was utilized

[[Source]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/30/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-rc.aspx)

**In Visual Studio 2013, CSS files that are included in your *project/solution* will now automatically be parsed and all HTML documents will gain CSS class intellisense.**

Comment: This is what I have concluded after reading around. Hopefully Microsoft can confirm/deny.

Comment: This is not my experience.  I have the same issue as the OP, and I have my css files included in my project.  I still don't get css class intellisense.

Comment: I just want to add something in case of VS 2013, **Do not forget to rebuild the project after adding the css files to the project**

Answer (score 13):

The Html editor wouldn't show css intellisense for me unless the style was embedded in the page itself. What worked for me was opening the html file using the Html Form Editor. Right click on the file and select open with and then choose Html Form Editor. This is for Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue on visual studio community 2015 and this fixes the problem with intellisense on css. Apart from not referencing correctly a css file this should the accepted answer. Great Job!

Answer (score 5):

After intellisense worked fine for a few weeks, I just ran into the same problem as the OP. Uninstalling and re-installing packages using NuGet did not resolve it.

Deleting the **bin** and **obj** directories from the project and the **.suo** file from the solution directory resolve it.

Comment: Finally! A tried a lot of solutrions, but this one helped me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This also happened to me when I create a web application in Visual Studio 2013, VS created automatically this code in the header but intellisense is sure not working for css classes.

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
```

What I did is just to manually link all my css one by one and can probably delete them after development.

```
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" /
```

It sure did the trick but I was hoping they will fix on the next update.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I have a Master page that contains the link to bootstrap -

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It was working before, which is why this was puzzling, and furthermore the website successfully uses the bootstrap CSS - it's just the intellisense feature that wasn't working.

I open the page that uses the Master page, and then click on VIEW, then MANAGED STYLES.  It displayed the bootstrap.css with a cautionary sign next to it.  When I hover over it said it could not find ../css/bootstrap.css.

So to fix the problem I changed the link in the Master page to use a tilde instead of periods:

```
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now all of the bootstrap CSS items appear in Manage Styles, and my intellisense is working.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. Are you definitely getting CSS intellisense in VS2013?

Comment: Yes I am - and my intellisense is working for all the classes defined in the CSS of my Master page.  What I also did was reset Visual Studio user settings with command line which I found in a similar post - but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

As Rowan Freeman wrote:

> In Visual Studio 2013, CSS files that are included in your project/solution will now automatically be parsed and all HTML documents will gain CSS class intellisense.

But:

> ASPX and other WebForm files using the legacy editor do not benefit from this implementation in VS 2013, but may adopt the new system in future releases.

**But you can still use this feature as follows:**

1. right click on the "default.aspx" file in the Solution Explorer
2. "open with"
3. select "HTML Editor"
4. "ok"

Answer (score 0):

The solution identified above for VS2012 will work with a slight variation.  You must include the folder like this within the css reference for the stylesheet.  Once you add this and save the page the intellisense will work.  This not the correct solution just a work around the bundling issue.