# Visual Studio intellisense for Bootstrap via CDN

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3, intellisense, cdn

I've installed Bootstrap via the Microsoft CDN like:

```
<head>
    ...
   <link href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

and

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.1.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Everything is working fine with Bootstrap, however, Visual Studio isn't giving me any kind of intellisense for the classes.

For example, typing

```
<div class="(intellisense should open here)
```

nothing comes up.

Is there any way to get intellisense from the CDN?

Comment: what version of visual studio?

Comment: @Scottie did you every get that to work? I am dealing with the same thing over here. VS 2013 Ultimate MVC. The css is being referenced in _Layout.cshtml...

Comment: No, I never did.  I just have the .css files in my solution and Intellisense picks them up, even though I never use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add CDN references to intelliSence for *javascript*, however, ***css* is not supported**.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 options]

You can **add the file to your project** and it will work, you dont need to add a ref to html, just to project and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you use {version} in this?

Comment: The `JavaScript\IntelliSense\References` node is not present in Visual Studio 2017. Even translating the `JavaScript` to `JavaScript/TypeScript` in the aforementioned path does not find the `References` node. I'm thinking that MS removed it.

Answer (score 34):

If you are working with **ASP.NET Core** project do as follows. VS only reference files inside the **wwwroot** folder. 
You need to open the .**csproj** file and add the following code segment.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="node_modules/**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After that VS will picking up intellicen from node_modules.

Comment: Works like a charm! Although I made my include specific to the bootstrap path as there are a lot of node modules I just don't care to see.

Comment: Thank you - was driving me nuts. Confirmed in VS 2019 16.3

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm this still works in a VS 2019 Razor project. I referenced `<None Include="node_modules\tailwindcss\dist\*.css" />` to get support for [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com)

Answer (score 5):

You need to install bootstrap through the NuGet Packages. Intellisense will start working after that.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Visual Studio**

Go in **Extensions and Updates** and then click on **Online** Tab.

In Search type **Bootstrap**.

Install following Packs to enable intellisense. Ensure that you have dragged bootstrap.css (or bootstrap.min.css and js file) before trying to insert snippet.

- Bootstrap Bundle
- Bootstrap Snippet Pack

[image]

Comment: This solution immediately fixed my intellisense problem.  Specifically the Bootstrap Bundle package.

Comment: Bootstrap Bundle is not available for VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the bootstrap nuget

Comment: I had to update the package from 3.4.1 to 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->the specific language ->IntelliSense

That should get the intellisense back up and running, worked for me before (think this is what you are looking for)

Comment: I know you answered "...-> **the specific language** ->IntelliSense" but **CSS** doesn't seem to have the IntelliSense-option-alernative?

Comment: what version of VS are you using? 2012? 2013?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Hi Hauns, there was a change between 2012 and 2013, this answer is the best I could offer, click the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21571678/4157770) - hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**I know this way is not exactly CDN, but it worked for me and you can still keep your packages up-to-date**

You can reference Bootstrap using Bower.

On the package.json you would have:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "TaskAngularJSApp",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
    "bower": "1.7.3"
  }
}
```

Then you have bower.json file like:

```
{
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "*"
    }
}
```

Then on your html you would reference bootstrap like

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I got help from:
[using grunt bower gulp npm with visual studio 2015 for a asp-net-4-5-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872622/using-grunt-bower-gulp-npm-with-visual-studio-2015-for-a-asp-net-4-5-project)

and

[Released Today: Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET 4.6, ASP.NET 5 & EF 7 Previews](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews) - On the "HTML Editor Updates" section

Answer (score 0):

In the `Content` folder copy `bootstrap.css`.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of the old Razor editor in the HTML settings helped me - https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/issues/5669

Answer (score 0):

Go to TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->HTML->Advanced->Razor-> Select True

[image]