# “Include in project” option missing for Asp.Net core project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, npm

I've created an Asp.Net core project in VS 2015 Update 3 and added 'twitter bootstrap' using npm. When I tried to include "bootstrap" folder into project, I couldn't find "Include in project" option in context menu. How do I fix this? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have the answer to this yet, I did notice this is not an issue with the version of Visual Studio (2015 Update 3). I have one web application that is .net Core and one that is not on this version of Visual Studio. The project that is not .net Core still has the Include in Project item working. The project that is .net Core has the include in project missing.

Comment: you are right, the problem only with asp.net core project