# Bootstrap 4 Autocomplete in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, intellisense, twitter-bootstrap-4

After upgrading to Bootstrap 4 my autocomplete (intellisense) isn't working correctly. It's still showing Bootstrap 3.

How can I make it work with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that Visual Studio gets its autocomplete data from the files in `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist`. Refresh the files with these steps:

- From the Project menu choose "Manage Bower Packages" Find Bootstrap,
  verify the version then click install
- Delete the contents of: `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist`
- Copy the contents of: `bower_components\bootstrap\dist` to:
  `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist`

You will also have to change any references in the code to point to the new version as well.

Comment: Generally you would use a task manager like Gulp or WebPack to handle copying these files for you. You can also use the built-in `bundler` as well (easier but much less powerful).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Does one generally set up the automation to pull major upgrades automatically or do we stay with the "safe" version until we've manually evaluated the impact?

Comment: This is handled by the package manager (npm, yarn, bower), not the task runner (gulp, webpack). I use NPM or Yarn rather than Bower (Bower has stopped development) but every package manager has this functionality. With npm/yarn you can tell it to grab the latest Major version using a `^` (`^1.0.0`) or the latest Minor version using a `~` (`~1.0.0`). The task runner simply grabs whatever version was fetched from the `bower_components` or `node_modules` folder during the build.

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped me, so I am posting it here too. 
Actually it was asked before here, in stackoverflow

[Visual Studio intellisense for Bootstrap via CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296472/visual-studio-intellisense-for-bootstrap-via-cdn)